# View updates everywhere but in current controller - angularJS

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-directive

EDIT: As asked, I'll explain a bit more efficiently !

I've been sitting in front of an annoying problem recently, which is that whenever I update a value inside a directive, the controllers I'm not currently "in" are the only ones to be updated properly.

Scenario example: Profile page is made of two controllers. Navbar_controller which is just currently displaying the user name :

```
<div ng-if="Auth.isAuthenticated">Hello, {{Auth.getCurrentUser().name}}</div>
```

The second controller , Profile_controller is here to update user values. This is a simple function in the angular first controller, which updates CurrentUser:

```
$scope.updateUser = function (type, form) {
    if (!$scope.modif)
        return ;

    $http.put('/api/users/' + Auth.getCurrentUser()._id + '/update', {type:type, modif:$scope.modif})
          .success(function (data, status) {
                $scope.user = Auth.setNewUser(data);
            })
            .error(function () {
                console.log("error");
            });
    };
```

When I update, for example, the name. I can see that the database has been modified properly. And indeed, navbar_controller got the update because a new name is printed in the div. However, Profile_controller doesn't get the update: the name printed in the profile page didn't change.

Here are the two basic functions in Auth.service.js :

```
getCurrentUser: function() {
    return currentUser;
  },

// 'user' is the data retrieved in http put request dot success
setNewUser: function(user) {
      currentUser = user;
      $rootScope.$broadcast(); // Navbar_controller is updated with or without this line
      return currentUser;
  }
```

Anyway, if I look at the navbar and its controller, which is calling Auth.getCurrentUser() method, the user values are instantly modified. I'e been using an ugly method consisting in modifying the controller values manually or by refreshing the page... But this isn't the way to go, right ?

There must be something with "$rootScope.$broadcast();", but I'm really new to Angular and other questions on stackoverflow are too specific to help me understand properly.

Thank you !

Comment: can you elaborate more, what's the actual issue? is the current user uptaing just inside the context you are calling your method?

Comment: is your problem on refresh?

Comment: try extending the object not replacing it with a  new one

Comment: @jack.the.ripper I believe it's the exact opposite. View updates anywhere but inside the context where I am calling the method. I updated my post to appear clearer

Comment: @charlietfl I tried and it had some effect indeed. But I believe it's strongly related to Matt's container

Comment: if your `user` is a primitive ( ie string) you will run into scope inheritance issues whereas you won;t with an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question was a little difficult to understand, but I think the problem is that you are reference a changing object in your various controllers. Here is an example to explain:

Service:

```
var myObject = { ... };
return { 
    getObject() { return myObject; }
    setObject(obj) { myObject = obj; }
};
```

Controller 1:

```
$scope.myObjA = Service.getObject();
```

Controller 2:

```
$scope.myObjB = Service.getObject();
```

Now on initialisation both controllers will be referencing the same object, so if you changed a property inside either controller (eg. `$scope.myObjB.name = 'bob';`), then the other controller would also see the name.

However if you changed the object itself in a controller (eg. `Service.setObject(newObj);`), then the controller will be referencing the new object, while the other controller will still be referencing the old one.

You can fix this by wrapping your service object in a container:

```
var cont = {
    user: ...
};

function getContainer() { return cont; }

function setNewUser(user) { cont.user = user; }
```

Then inside your controllers, get the container (not the user):

```
$scope.cont = Service.getContainer();
```

And inside your html:

```
<div>{{cont.user.name}}</div>
```

Now when you update the user, all attached controllers will be updated.

Comment: That worked indeed ! Would you mind explaining a bit more because it appears to me that user is kind of a container too

Comment: When two scopes bind to `x`, if any property of `x` such as `x.name` is changed, then it will change on both scopes. However, if `x` itself is changed, then one scope will point to the new `x`, and the other scope will point to the old `x`. By wrapping `x` in a container, both scopes point to the same container, so changing `x` is reflected by both scopes (as the container doesn't change). Hope that helps (don't forget to mark question).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it really helped. Here is a talk about scope inheritance in case someone steps in here : http://youtu.be/ZhfUv0spHCY?t=30m1s

Answer (score 0):

Well I'd try to change and store the user information in $rootScope, for your scenario could be a good fit.

```
getCurrentUser: function() {
   $rootScope.currentUser===undefined ? 'no User': $rootScope.currentUser;
  },

setNewUser: function(user) {
      $rootScope.currentUser = user;
      //$rootScope.$broadcast(); no need to broadcast
      return getCurrentUser();
  }
```

in that way currentUser will be updated in different scopes as needed!

I'll quote AnuglarJs [FAQ](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq) regarding to $rootscope:

**$rootScope exists, but it can be used for evil**

> Occasionally there are pieces of data that you want to make global to
>   the whole app. For these, you can inject $rootScope and set values on
>   it like any other scope. Since the scopes inherit from the root scope,
>   these values will be available to the expressions attached to
>   directives like ng-show just like values on your local $scope.
>
> Of course, global state sucks and you should use $rootScope sparingly,
>   like you would (hopefully) use with global variables in any language.
>   In particular, don't use it for code, only data. If you're tempted to
>   put a function on $rootScope, it's almost always better to put it in a
>   service that can be injected where it's needed, and more easily
>   tested.
>
> Conversely, don't create a service whose only purpose in life is to
>   store and return bits of data.

Comment: Indeed, but I heard using $rootScope was kind of a bad practice. Do you think it should be used for such an important var, as user is used everywhere on my app ?

Comment: for this case it's not a bad practice, I'd rather prefer to have the user info in the rootscope, rather than to copy the informatin everytime I need, that's way more boilerplate code for such a simple task, the use case for changing the information of a user is not going to happen very often

Comment: You shouldn't use `$rootScope` to store anything. A service is much more suited to this situation.